# Is there a way to disable scaling for all the WPF application even if windows has some scale per monitor or system-wide scale?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, scaling, dpi

I need to have WPF windows that is always 1:1 with physical pixels (DPI is always 96), and by this time I found no way to do this: application manifest or API methods for the awareness are useless, they just changing ways how the content is being scaled: as a bitmap or by the application. I need application always has the fixed, 100% scale, even if system settings are 200% per monitor or per whole system. Do you guys know some ways that could help?

Comment: You'd need to calculate the scaling applied to the monitor the window is on and inverse that, use it to scale the window content. Size the window to content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who will be looking for the similar solution:

I found no way to force application do not scale together with the operating system, but found how to keep 1:1 scale.

First thing you need to do is to define that the application is dpi-aware, so it will not be scaled by the system but by application itself. Here is app.manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

Then you'll be able to get current scale for the visual:

```
double xScale = PresentationSource.FromVisual(someVisual).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
double yScale = PresentationSource.FromVisual(someVisual).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
```

And then you could bind layout transform to control (image in my case) to cancel scaling effect:

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ScaleX}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=ScaleY}" />
</Image.LayoutTransform>
```

Please note that proportions should be inverted, so ScaleX and ScaleY will have these values:

```
ScaleX = 1 / scaleX;
ScaleY = 1 / scaleY;
```

Comment: It is a neat way. My suggestion is to use `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi` method to get DpiScale of the target Visual and refer its `DpiScaleX` and `DpiScaleY` properties. The result will be the same but slightly less code.

Comment: Sure, but it is available only in .net core 3.0, .net framework 4.6.2 and later versions. I am using .net framework 4.5, that's why

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can suppress all automatic scaling by declaring `True/PM` in the application manifest, which means that the application takes full responsibility for scaling, and then ignoring the `WM_DPICHANGED` message when it comes.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source?.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private const int WM_DPICHANGED = 0x02E0;

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == WM_DPICHANGED)
        {
            handled = true;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure if a user can override this behavior by any OS settings.

Comment: Yes, that's the way application will not change scale during the lifetime and it works. But how to prevent application from scaling at the startup? It is not receiving WM_DPICHANGED at the startup

Comment: You are right. It has no effect on the initial rendering.