How Can I track the Last DPI which is sent by WM_DPICHANGED in WPF?
I want to scale my WPF application according to available screen DPI. I know there Per Monitor DPI aware available but that are completely different what I want to achieve. I want to disable scaling for my WPF application even if windows has some scale per monitor or system-wide scale. I understand that if the system scaling is disabled then what scale factor Windows decides to use is the main goal of mine.
To scale my WPF application according to initial DPI at the startup time I need to get the current DPI. And The current DPI for a window always equals the last DPI sent by WM_DPICHANGED.
here is my code :
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private HwndSource hwndSource;   
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {    
            hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual((Visual) sender) as HwndSource;
            hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
        }
        private const int WM_DPICHANGED = 0x02E0;
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_DPICHANGED)
            {
                handled = true;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

Have a look on this Code. This is how I disable System scaling. But the down factor is, Initial DPI is not detected when I restart my Application at different screen resolution (DPI). It is not receiving WM_DPICHANGED at the startup and It has no effect on the initial rendering.
I just need to find the last DPI sent by WM_DPICHANGED. If somehow I track that, then I can easily scale my application according to that. So, there no initial DPI problem.
I know that, I talk a lot and the whole question is quite confusing. So, here I make the summery of the question and what I want as answer. I divided this into two part -

How to track the Last DPI which is sent by WM_DPICHANGED?

After getting the last WM_DPICHANGED, want to apply that in my WPF interface scaling so, that the Initial DPI is detected and my Application scale by itself not by the System / OS.


There lot of C# based solution available in Stack overflow but none of them are working and quite old not works in current Windows 11 environment. Please try to add/modify my given Win32 based code. Other pure C# based code solution also welcome if each step is described properly.

WM_DPICHANGED message does not include the information on the previous DPI. Then, why don't you try to get the monitor DPI which your WPF app belongs when your app starts?

Thank you very much sir for your comment. I hope you understand what I want to achieve in my WPF Application. Can you please give your valuable answer with proper code and step by step guide. If you do that then I definitely accept your answer.

Respected sir, You give this code as an answer almost 5 years ago. Can you please give me an answer. I am ready to give you everything you want. I am in great danger please help me, I loose my job as result. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538032/is-there-a-way-to-disable-scaling-for-all-the-wpf-application-even-if-windows-ha

It should be simple. You can find a code example to get the monitor DPI from the window handle and call it in Window.OnSourceInitialized method.

If you do that, I can definitely accept your answer. Believe me this DPI, Scaling & Win32 are above my head. Please Do that I accept your answer immediately. Even ready to give you anything you want. I stuck here for almost six months. I am forever grateful to you if you do this for me.

Respected sir, I hope you read my comment, I get the Monitor DPI using PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(LayoutRoot);
double dpiX, dpiY;
if (source != null)
{
dpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
dpiY = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
} but I also try to call that through a method in Window.OnSourceInitialized. But that does not working. please help, I follow all your steps but still I don't get the desire result.

You need to understand the most important thing when asking a question in SO is to provide a complete, minimal reproducible example which is ready for other people to try and find the root cause. For example, a repo in GitHub would be convenient. I suggested a general idea but I don't know what you are actually doing.

Thank you very much sir for your reply. I just want to disable system scaling of a WPF application. Just have a look this stack overflow link, almost 5 years ago you tried to answer that. The code is given by you on that post, I just pick up your code. The problem of your code is it  It is not receiving WM_DPICHANGED at the startup. Here is the link, please have a look, it's your own old question  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538032/is-there-a-way-to-disable-scaling-for-all-the-wpf-application-even-if-windows-ha

@emoacht I am still waiting for your reply. Believe me nothing works in my case. Just consider me as your little brother and help me in my difficult situation just for humanitarian purposes. Saving someone is best.

You are heading into a world of pain by trying to fight WPF over DPI control.  I would suggest you have an X-Y problem and need to post a question regarding your real issue, or use the normal WPF support for high-DPI.
Regardless, filtering WM_DPICHANGED (setting handled = true to prevent WPF from processing a message) does not disable system scaling, it prevents WPF from listening to DPI information.  System scaling is influenced by the manifest <dpiAware> element or via Set*DpiAwareness* functions - which WPF is likely calling.  The details would depend upon the manifest of your application and the version of WPF/.Net/dotnet and windows you are using.
WM_DPICHANGED provides the new DPI as a parameter.  Specifically, the low word of wParam.
        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_DPICHANGED)
            {
                handled = true;
                var dpi = unchecked((int)(wParam & 0xffff));
                Console.WriteLine($"New DPI: {dpi}");
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }


Respected sir, I am very much sorry for asking X-Y problem. Actually, this P/Invoke type Win32 codes are above my head. The code you given me is quite understandable but unfortunately I face an error at this line (wParam & 0xffff)). The error visual studio gives me is Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type IntPtr and 'int'.

If you are still on .NET Framework, you would need to cast to a long first.  var dpi = unchecked((int)((ulong)wParam & 0xffff));

Love the way you try, but your code is not working. Actually I developed my application in full HD (19201080) resolution. I run my application and I change the screen resolution to 1366768 and app perfectly scale but as soon as I restart my Application in Lower resolution My app don't detect the initial dpi and thus it's not properly scale.  Any idea how the initial rendering problem will be solved? You previously say about per monitor DPI, I already try that, that have different purpose. I don't want that. Can you please give another code so, that last dpi became initial DPI when I restart.

You should not have to do any interop code for per-monitor high-DPI with WPF on any supported version of windows or .Net (requires W10 1607 and .Net 4.6.2 or higher).  Full example is PerMonitorDPI.  Only requirement is to add manifest settings.  (The app.config setting is only required for prior versions.)

Thank you again for your reply. I suggest you to visit this Stack overflow link So, that you can easily understand what I want to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538032/is-there-a-way-to-disable-scaling-for-all-the-wpf-application-even-if-windows-ha
